# Await Task.Delay(x) changing UI or completing instantly

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await

I am trying to change the image of a `PictureBox` for a few seconds and then change it back whilst keeping the UI thread unblocked and the UI responsive.

I was previously using `Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)` to show the new image and then change it back but that stops any user input to the application for the entire length of the sleep.

I then found out about creating a Wait on a Task that is completed Asynchronously and after reading up on it, put together the below:

```vb
Private Async Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.Click
    saveList(listName)

    PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Temp_Image
    Await Task.Delay(5000)
    PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image
End Sub
```

The problem is, it appears that the task completes almost instantly rather than waiting the 5 seconds as expected. After breaking and debugging the code, it seems to change the image correctly to "Temp_Image" and as soon as it hits the `Await Task.Delay(5000)` line, it changes the image back to the "Normal_Image" instantly.

Is there a better way to complete these "animations" on the UI thread without blocking it, or am I using this `Async Task.Delay()` incorrectly?

**EDIT:** Ah, I've stumbled across the issue. The MouseUp and MouseLeave Events are firing and cancelling the visual change (presumably as this is asynchronous, so it returns to processing tasks/events) - is there a way to disable these events when waiting on an Async task?

```vb
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.MouseLeave
        PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox.MouseUp
        PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image
    End Sub
```

Comment: Code works as posted.

Comment: dont know about vb.net, but in C# this should work like you posted it.

Comment: That's bizarre. So the image changes to the Temp image on the `PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Temp_Image` line, but F8 on the `Await Task.Delay(5000)` line changes the image back to the Normal image for me.

Comment: Try commenting out the `saveList` line.

Comment: Ah, I've stumbled across the issue. The MouseUp and MouseLeave Events are firing and cancelling the visual change (presumably as this is asynchronous, so it returns to processing tasks/events) - is there a way to disable these events when waiting on an Async task?

Comment: Post your MouseUp and MouseLeave code.

Comment: They're literally just resetting the image to the "Normal" image. I've posted as an edit to the question though.

Comment: Welp, that about clears it up.

Comment: Yea... not a strong moment for me...

Comment: Why do you have both Click and MouseUp handlers?

Comment: I only recently added the Click event, so I've already removed the MouseUp one now which solves that problem. MouseLeave is going to trigger this. Is there a way of disabling or blocking the event if an Async task is running?

Comment: By the way, if you break on the PictureBox_Click `PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image` you will see that it is only hit after 5 seconds, regardless of the other handlers. This `presumably as this is asynchronous, so it returns to processing tasks/events` is not the case.

Comment: You can set up a modal boolean which turns False when you fire the async function, which will turn it True when it finishes. Then check for this boolean before doing anything you don't want to happen during the async function.

Comment: Sure. Just use a boolean flag to signal that you are waiting? If you are concerned with the treading implications, you can Interlock.Increment a counter or other synchronization tool.

Comment: I've always used the "BlockFlag" Boolean method but wanted to check that was a valid method of doing this or if there was a better Best Practice way. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The reason flags sometimes don't work is when there is multi-threading going on and both threads race to set/access the flag at the same time. You can synchronize around this. In reality, it would probably not happen in your case and you can just use a flag without worry.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean - in this instance you're right; this setup shouldn't trigger this issue. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm experimenting with your code and I am able to click on the edge pixel and immediately move, triggering the MouseLeave to happen before the flag is set. It's an edge case. You may want to consider it.

Comment: My previous comment is not about an edge case, rather a non-click. See my answer for details on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a flag to signal not to change the image while waiting

```vb
Private flag As Boolean = False

Private Async Sub PictureBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.Click
    flag = True
    PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Temp_Image
    Await Task.Delay(1000)
    PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image
    flag = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox.MouseLeave
    If Not flag Then PictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Normal_Image
End Sub
```

The mouse must remain in the PictureBox for the entirety of the click. I mean the mouse down and up. So if you press, move away, then release, only the MouseLeave event will occur. You may consider using MouseDown or MouseUp, depending on your desired behavior, or leave it as-is if this is acceptable.